# Hibernate trying to put a heir class object into his brother element

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

The title sounds lame and confuse, but here is the problem:

I have an entity called *Price*, which have two elements called "*status*" and "*approvalStatus*". Those elements are from classes *Status* and *ApprovalStatus*, respectively. Both of the later extends the *Domain* class, which maps a multiple domain table.

In my jUnit, when i call for a list of *Status* or a list of *ApprovalStatus*, hibernate bring then without problems. But when I call for my Price entity, I get the following problem:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object with id: 1 was not of the specified subclass: net.x.ApprovalStatus (loaded object was of wrong class class net.x.Status)] with root cause
org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object with id: 1 was not of the specified subclass: net.x.ApprovalStatus (loaded object was of wrong class class net.x.Status)
```

As a test, I removed the "*status*" element off my *Price* entity. AND IT WORKED! The issue just pop up when I have multiples elements which classes Inherit from the same entity.

Here are my classes (manually stripped down, way too big :/)

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="CD_DOMAIN_GROUP", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@Table(name="DOMAIN")
@Cacheable
public abstract class Domain {
    @Id
    @Column(name="CD_DOMAIN")
    private Integer code;

    public Domain () {

    }

    public Domain (Integer code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Integer getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(Integer code) {
        this.code= code;
    }
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
@Cacheable
public class Status extends Domain implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static Integer ACTIVE= 1;
    public static Integer INATIVE = 2;

    public Status() {

    }

    public Status(Integer code) {
        super(code);
    }
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
@Cacheable
public class ApprovalStatus extends Domain implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static Integer APPROVED = 1;
    public static Integer REJECTED = 2;
    public static Integer PENDING = 3;

    public ApprovalStatus () {

    }

    public ApprovalStatus (Integer code) {
        super(code);
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name="PRICE")
public class Price  {
    @Id
    @Column(name="CD_PRICE")
    private Integer code;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_STATUS", referencedColumnName="CD_DOMAIN")
    private Status status;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_APPROVAL_STATUS", referencedColumnName="CD_DOMAIN")
    private ApprovalStatus approvalStatus;
}
```

**Does anyone knows what is going on? Am I missing some configuration? Is my mapping somehow wrong?**

I'm using hibernate 4.2.13.Final.